# How to transition pages in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, gatsby, react-spring

I'm trying to use React Spring to transition pages in Gatsby, similar to this implementation with React Pose - http://joshdcuneo.com/gatsby-animate-page-transitions/

Here is a Code Sandbox of my implementation attempt - https://codesandbox.io/s/great-sky-3g2lo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

It uses Gatsby's `wrapPageElement` API to add the transition in `gatsby-browser.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { animated, useTransition } from 'react-spring'

const SimpleSpring = ({ children, props }) => {
  const transitions = useTransition(props.path, null, {
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: { duration: 3000 }
  })

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      {transitions.map(({ item, key, props }) => (
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          {children}
        </animated.div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <SimpleSpring props={props}>{element}</SimpleSpring>
}
```

Currently, when a page transition is triggered, React Spring is animating the origin page out and the target page in [as can be seen in this deployed example (press "Go to page 2")](https://gatsby-spring-page-transition.jakeelder.now.sh). That is to say that during the transition period, there are two pages in the DOM that are fading in/out as specified in the hook. However, the source page instantly updates to have the DOM structure of the target page when the transition begins. So, there are two identical pages, one fading out, one fading in.

What am I missing. I've tried all sorts of things with `useRef` and `React.cloneElement` but I can't get the origin page to remain as it should until the transition has completed.

**Notes**

- I've used a long duration for the animation rather than a spring to be able to better see what's happening
- Same with layout. Once the DOM is reflecting as it should, these pages will be `position: absolute` during transition so they overlap. I currently have them side by side to debug
- Repo on Github - https://github.com/JakeElder/gatsby-react-spring-page-transition
- Deployed app - https://gatsby-spring-page-transition.now.sh